# Getting Google satellite images (via plugin) to behave well in QGIS with map created with different CRS

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

How to get Google satellite images (via the plugin) to behave well in QGIS with a map created with a difference CRS?

I have a problem using the Google Image layer plug in - at some scales, it won’t match the rest of the project (but does at others).

The project started with Tiff files imported from GB Ordinance Survey and set the CRS to EPSG:27700 - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid (which I think these tiles default to).

I then added a couple of shapefile layers (set to the same CRS). One has point data, the other is a polygon which defines a site boundary.

I then added (via the plug in) the google satellite image layer.

Whenever I add this layer to any project, this always defaults to a view where the whole world is repeated several times across the screen.  If I zoom in by one click from there, it seems to find itself ok and the site boundary matches the OS tile and the satellite image.

However on this project (and a previous one), when I zoom in too far, suddenly the site boundary doesn't match the same area on the google image (about 1:1000) - it is quite a jump.  I can zoom back out any amount and the polygon and google image match fine.

When the polygon and google image don’t match up, if I bring the OS tile above the Google image, I can see that the polygon and OS tile have remained lined-up.

I know Google use a different CRS - WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator, which I assume is the root of the problem, but there must be a fix.  I’ve tried changing the google image layer’s CRS to match the rest of the project with the obvious result that it goes even further off (“sorry we don’t have image for here”) and right clicking on the OS layer and selecting “set project CRS from layer” doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug of the Openlayers plugin:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6822

Try to use bing imagery as an alternative.